# Show that each polynomial $p\in P^4$ can be written as $p=f+g$ where $f\in L$ and $g\in M.$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

In real vector space $P^4$ of polynomials whose degree is not greater than 4 we are given the subsets:

$$L=\{f\in P^4: f(2)=0\}$$
and $$M=\{g\in P^4: g(-2)=0\}.$$

$1)$ Prove that they are subspaces and find one basis for each of them.

$2)$ Show that each polynomial $p\in P^4$ can be written as $p=f+g$ where $f\in L$ and $g\in M.$

What I did:

Let $e,f \in M$. We have to show that $\alpha e+\beta f \in M$.

$(\alpha e+\beta f)(2)=\alpha e(2)+\beta f(2)=\alpha \times 0 +\beta \times 0=0$

$\Rightarrow \alpha e+ \beta f \in L$ so $L$ is a subspace of $P^4$.

To find the basis:

$f(x)=ax^4+bx^3+cx^2+dx+e$ $f(2)=16a+8b+4c+2d+e=0, (a,b,c,d,e)\in \Bbb R^5$.

$f\in L  \Leftrightarrow f(x)=a(x^4-16)+b(x^3-8)+c(x^2-4)+d(x-2)$

So one basis for $L$ is $\{(x^4-16),(x^3-8),(x^2-4),(x-2)\}$.

Is this correct?

Similarly I checked that $M$ is a subspace, and I found the basis for $M=\{(x^4-16),(x^3+8),(x^2-4),(x+2)\}$

How do I now prove that each polynomial $p\in P^4$ can be written as $p=f+g$ where $f\in L$ and $g\in M$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To prove the last assertion it suffices to prove that the basis elements of $P^4$, namely {$1, x, x^2, x^3, x^4$} can be written as a linear combination of the basis elements of $M$ and $L$.

Comment: Can you please elaborate? What would be the first step?

Comment: Using your choice of basis, for examplel, $1 = \frac{1}{4} \cdot (x+2) -  \frac{1}{4} \cdot (x-2) $ you can do the same for the other basis elements.

Comment: So I should write $1=A(x-2)+ B(x+2)$, $x=C(x-2)+D(x-2)$, $x^2=E(x^2-4)+F(x^2-4), x^3=G(x^3-8)+H(x^3+8), x^4=I(x^4-16)+J(x^4-16)$. Is that it?  But how do I know which scalars to choose?

Comment: Basis element can be written as $x^n = (x^n - 2^n) + 2^n( 1) = (x^n -2^n) + 2^n \cdot \frac{1}{4}( (x+2) -(x-2)) $ where the first and the third term are basis elements of L while the second is a basis element of M. I didn't think it through, it wasn't straightforward, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose we had $p(x) = ax^4 + bx^3 + cx^2 + dx + e$. Try representing this as a vector $(a,b,c,d,e)$. You have bases $\{(1,0,0,0,-16),(0,1,0,0,-8),(0,0,1,0,-4),(0,0,0,1,-2)\}$ and $\{(1,0,0,0,-16),(0,1,0,0,8),(0,0,1,0,-4),(0,0,0,1,2)\}$. Given those eight vectors, find how to make an arbitrary linear combination; note that you have five linearly independent vectors in a vector space of dimension 5, so this is possible.

Comment: Do you mean I should write it as $A(1,0,0,0,-16)+B(0,1,0,0,-8)+C(0,0,1,0,-4)+D(0,0,0,1,-2)+E(0,1,0,0,8)=(a,b,c,d,e)$  


and then show $A,B,C,D,E$ in terms of $a,b,c,d,e$?

Comment: Yep. When you can do that, you can choose $f$ and $g$ such that, if $p(x) = ax^5 + \ldots + e$, then $p = f + g$.